# Ruby gems not being loaded

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am running Ruby 1.9.3 on Debian, with no Rails. I have a script that needs mysql, so I ran `gem install mysql`, and it installed fine.

However, when I execute the script I get a "**cannot load such file**" error.

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from db-test.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Further info: **I have updated to RBENV, but now the mysql won't install.**

`ruby --version` gives:

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

`which ruby` gives:

```
/home/poconnor/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Output of `gem environment` is:

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.1.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/poconnor/ruby/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/poconnor/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/poconnor/ruby/gems/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/poconnor/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/poconnor/ruby/gems
     - /lib/ruby/gems/1.9.3
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/poconnor/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/bin
     - /home/poconnor/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/poconnor/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/poconnor/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/poconnor/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin
     - /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin
     - /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin
     - /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin
```

When I try `gem install mysql` I get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/poconnor/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/poconnor/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mlib
        --without-mlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-zlib
        --without-zlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mygcclib
        --without-mygcclib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/poconnor/ruby/gems/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/poconnor/ruby/gems/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Help much appreciated on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much to Josh and grenierm5 for their time and advice - RBENV was a great help, definitely makes life easier.

The answer is two-part: RBENV to solve my weird environment issues, but then also to solve the mysql gem install issue, I had to install the following Debian packages:

```
apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

This was answered here: [ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension (mysql2 on rails 3.2.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051448/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-mysql2-on-rails-3-2-3)

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue with your setup.  `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1` indicated the gem is installed under ruby 1.9.1 but you mention that you are using ruby 1.9.3.  Are you using a ruby version control system such as [RVM](https://rvm.io) or [RBENV](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)?

**Update**

Based on your `gem environment` output, there is definitely something wrong with your system ruby setup.  It says it is ruby version 1.9.3 but it points to a folder called 1.9.1.  My recommendation is to forget about your system ruby and install RBENV(linked above).  It is a simplified version of RVM and I believe it would fix your problem.  It will also greatly simplify your life later when you decide you want to use ruby 2 and beyond.

Comment: Yes, when I do ruby --version I get ruby 1.9.3p194. I had RVM installed before (didn't really know what I was doing), and have since removed it using rvm implode, and gem uninstall rvm. Is there anything else I could do to sort out version setup issues?

Comment: @pokero can you run `which ruby` in your terminal and paste the output?

Comment: Sure, I get /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: @pokero when you had rvm, did you install ruby 1.9.1?

Comment: Hi Josh, I honestly can't remember. It was over a month ago unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks again. I have installed RBENV now, but the mysql gem will not install. I have updated the original question above with the new info.

Answer (score 1):

**Items to verify:**

1. Add /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ to your PATH variable
2. require 'rubygems' before you require 'mysql' in your script <-- My bad. This is irrelevant in 1.9 because 'rubygems' is implicitly required

**Recommendation:** Use rvm (https://rvm.io/rvm/install) to manage ruby and gem installations (with gemsets)

**Update:**

Josh is correct that you should use a ruby versioning tool like RVM or RBENV, however in the short-term you could modify your .bashrc file and add:

- export GEM_HOME=$HOME/ruby/gems
- export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.3
- export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
- export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/ruby/gems/bin

...and then run `source ~/.bashrc` to change the gem path to 1.9.3 and then `gem install mysql` again.

Comment: Thanks, I added that dir to my path and have require "rubygems" before mysql, but the exact same issue is there.

Comment: It looks like a permissions issue. Perhaps this issue is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518665/ruby-gem-environment-issue-loaderror-no-such-file-to-load-robots?rq=1

Comment: I actually chmod'ed the whole /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory to be 777, but same result.

Comment: Please post the output from 'gem environment' in the original post.

Comment: I tried that (the bashrc changes), but no luck. I have installed RBENV, but gem will not install now.